# SwiftUI change between 2 texts every time when a button is clicked

Tags: swift, button, swiftui

I'm coding an application with Xcode and SwiftUI and have the following problem:
When I press a button some TextViews should appear like:

```
@State var showAnswer = false

Button (action: {
   self.showAnswer = true
                    
}

if self.showAnswer {
   VStack(spacing: 20) {
      Text("example")
      ...
      Text("example")

}
```

My question is, how is it possible to change on every click between "example" and e.g "example_two". So when I click the button "example" should appear, when I click it the next time, it should be "example_two". The third click will be "example" again.
How can I do that?

Comment: Your question and code are not clear. Please add proper code and which text you want to change button title text or outside the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do something like this:

```
@State var showAnswer = false
@State var toggleText = false

Button (action: {
   self.showAnswer = true
   self.toggleText.toggle()
                    
}

if self.showAnswer {
   VStack(spacing: 20) {
      Text(toggleText ? "example" : "example_two")
      ...
      Text(toggleText ? "example_two" : "example")
}
```

after pressing on the `button`, it triggers `toggleText`, which triggers UI to refresh